# Sort list containing dictionary according to date

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I want to sort the below-provided list based on the 'date' value using DSA and not any external/internal modules in Python. I tried but am unable to come up with any working solution here.
Kindly help me with that.

```
a = [{"date":[14,1,2020],"stockValue":-0.57357144},
     {"date":[9,2,2021],"stockValue":-0.66407406},
     {"date":[10,2,2020],"stockValue":-0.62166667}]
```

The expected answer will be as below.

```
a = [{"date":[14,1,2020],"stockValue":-0.57357144},
     {"date":[10,2,2020],"stockValue":-0.62166667},
     {"date":[9,2,2021],"stockValue":-0.66407406}]
```

Comment: What does DSA mean here?

Answer (score 0):

```
a.sort(key=lambda x: x['date'], reverse=True)
```